# Python Structure elements as arrays

Tags: python, c, arrays

I want to create a Python structure similar to the C structure below. Notice that the members are arrays. The reason is because I will be calling a C function which expects arrays of chars in the structure.

```
struct
{ 
    unsigned char vendorListNumber[5];
    unsigned char vendorNumber[5];
}  vendrRecord;
```

Looking at this page (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char), I don't see a type which is an array or string.

Looking at `__init__.py` I see this:

```
class c_char(_SimpleCData):
    _type_ = "c"
c_char.__ctype_le__ = c_char.__ctype_be__ = c_char
_check_size(c_char)
```

I don't understand this syntax yet ... is there a way I can make my own class which will give me an array of chars?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from ctypes import c_ubyte, Structure

class VendorRecord(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("vendorListNumber", c_ubyte * 5),
                ("vendorNumber", c_ubyte * 5)]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think that worked. Does the following prove that (a slightly different example)?

`class vendrRecord(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1                                            # pack the struct
    _fields_ = [
        ('vendorListNumber',c_char * 5),
        ('r2',c_ubyte),
        ('p1',c_ubyte),
        ('id',c_uint)]

print (vendrRecord.vendorListNumber)
print (vendrRecord.r2)

--- output ---
<Field type=c_char_Array_5, ofs=0, size=5>
<Field type=c_ubyte, ofs=5, size=1>
`

Comment: @Eddy That's ok, but take in account that `c_char` might be signed. So if you want an `unsigned char` then use `c_ubyte`.

Comment: Can I please take this opportunity to ask how my comment should be formatted as if it is code? I tried putting back ticks around the code (as suggested in the help) but as you can see that didn't work.

Comment: @Eddy Actually in comments that's the best you can achieve!

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I have no rep points:

Can you just use a dictionary? Here is the syntax:

```
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'};
```

This was taken from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Thanks.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to designate an array.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend you to check out NumPy.